Using tcl to get a list of files from tar.gz
I am trying to get a list of files from tar.gz file using tcl.  I can extract the data from the tar.gz but how can I get the names of the file?
set f [open $tarFile]
zlib push gunzip $f
set data [read $f]
close $f


You are missing a couple of important things, primary of which is opening your file in binary mode.
You need not just zlib but the tar package.
package require zlib
package require tar

Then you can extract all the filenames:
proc names.tar.gz tarFileName {
    set f [open $tarFileName {RDONLY BINARY}]
    zlib push gunzip $f
    set names [::tar::contents $f -chan]
    close $f
    return $names
}

You can display them easily by joining with a newline:
puts [join [names.tar.gz $tarFileName] \n]

Remember that if the file cannot be opened it will throw an error (that you should catch using either a try or catch construct).

zlib is builtin in 8.6

@glennjackman Yes, but you should still require the packages you use, IMHO

I was not even aware that there is a package for it: the man page does not even mention it.

@glennjackman yeah, that's weird. It has been a package for some years now, but Tcl docs don't always list all the info they should, lol

That builtin package does nothing except provide support for package require zlib itself; it is solely for compatibility with pre-8.6 code, and the zlib command is now independent of it.

Extending Dúthomhas's answer, if you want to do multiple things with the channel, the gunzip filter has to come off, and you need to seek back to the top:
set f [open $tarFile]
chan configure $f -translation binary
zlib push gunzip $f
set names [::tar::contents $f -chan]

# find the stats for each file
foreach name $names {
    # seek back to the top of the open file
    chan pop $f
    seek $f 0
    zlib push gunzip $f

    puts [::tar::stat $f $name -chan]
}

# now we can close the file
close $f


I know you said "using Tcl". An alternate method is to call out to tar, passing the open channel as tar's stdin:
set f [open $tarFile]
chan configure $f -translation binary
zlib push gunzip $f
set names [exec tar tf - <@ $f]

But then you might as well let tar handle the compression
set names [exec tar ztf $tarFile]

